# sencha command not found using docker

Tags: docker, sencha-cmd, alpine-linux

I'm trying to build an image for sencha using ruby:alpine and following the instructions indicated in this [link](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/guides/getting_started/getting_started.html)

As the title says, i can't get alpine to recognize sencha command. this [link](https://docs.sencha.com/cmd/guides/intro_to_cmd.html#intro_to_cmd_-_command_not_found) suggest that I should have sencha in the PATH environment variable (it also says that I should close the terminal and open a new one, but I don't know if that's even possible)

I tried to add sencha to the PATH variable by writing this in my dockerfile

```
RUN export PATH = /my/path/to/sencha/cmd:$PATH
```

Note that in this case `$PATH` in not an `ENV` element. After that, I add `RUN echo $PATH` to check if the path was actually added to the variable, but it seems that it didn't work...

Next step calls `RUN sencha`, where I get the error of command not found

Comment: should it be `export`?

Comment: sorry, that wasn't copied directly from my code. I just checked and it's written just as you said. I'll edit that right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me

```
ENV PATH="/my/path/to sencha/cmd:$PATH"
```